# JsonMediaTypeFormatter.WriteToStreamAsync throws when writing from MemoryStream

Tags: asp.net-web-api

I've a method on my Web Api Controller that returns MemoryStream. Problem occurs when JsonMediaTypeFormatter is selected by DefaultContentNegotiator and WriteToStreamAsync is called. (I'm using default media type formatters)

Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException: Error getting value from 'MemStreamMaxLength on 'System.IO.MemoryStream'

Following code simulates the situation:

```
var stream = new MemoryStream();
stream.WriteByte(1);
stream.Position = 0;

var formatter = new JsonMediaTypeFormatter();

var writeStream = new MemoryStream();
formatter.WriteToMemoryStreamAsync(stream.GetType(), stream, writeStream, null, null).Wait();
```